# Get physical screen size, not window size in Flutter

Tags: linux, flutter

I'm trying to make a utility bar that spans the width of my display. I'm using [window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) to manage placement and sizing, but it looks like I can't set the width to my display's width. I can hard-code it, which works, but trying to grab the width results in a null value, making the width default to 1280 pixels.

Note that the methods I've tried have been able to pull the display size of the window, but not of the actual display.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Headbar());
}

class Headbar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) async{
      await windowManager.setTitleBarStyle(TitleBarStyle.hidden);
      await windowManager.setPosition(const Offset(0, 0));
      // await windowManager.setResizable(false); // Make sure people can't resize this... but it breaks the window resizing below. Temporarily commented out.
      // await windowManager.setSkipTaskbar(true); // Remove icon from the taskbar
  });
      double scrwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      double scrheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      windowManager.setSize(Size(scrwidth, 50)); // Still working on this...


    return const MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World!'),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

What happens:
[image: Utility bar takes up only a litttle more than half the width of the display.]

For reference, the target platform is Linux Desktop, which I'm using as my environment as well.
Outputing the values of `scrwidth` and `scrheight` via `print()` yields the height and width of the window, not the physical display.

I've also tried the following methods that don't work:

- `FlutterView` and/or `platformDispatcher` - Just not working for some reason... and also bork window_manager.
- `window` is depricated and will be removed, so I'd like to avoid using this since it'll be removed.
- Setting width to some unholy number and height to the height and maximizing the window - crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`screen_retriever`](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_retriever) package, which is a dependency of `window_manager`, is capable of handling such a task.

```
...
Display primaryDisplay = await screenRetriever.getPrimaryDisplay();
double displayWidth = primaryDisplay.size.width;
double displayHeight = primaryDisplay.size.height;
windowManager.setSize(Size(displayWidth, displayHeight)); // Set the size of the window (use case)
...
```

The variables `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` have the width and height of the display in pixels, respectively.

If you can't use the methods provided by `screen_retriever`, you may need to import it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PlatformDispatcher` to get screen size.

```dart
   final screens = PlatformDispatcher.instance.displays;
   final fSize = screens.first.size;
   print('fds: $fSize');
```

Another ways is from context.

```dart
View.of(context).display.size;
```

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: S3Size()));
}

class S3Size extends StatelessWidget {
  const S3Size({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screens = PlatformDispatcher.instance.displays;
    final pdFSize = screens.first.size;
    print('PDSize: $pdFSize');

    print(View.of(context).display.size);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("From PlatformDispatcher: $pdFSize"),
          Text("From View: ${View.of(context).display.size}"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As stated in the original question: FlutterView and/or platformDispatcher - Just not working for some reason... and also bork window_manager.

Also, this is supposed to be dynamic. Wouldn't using Finals make the value fixed after compiling?

Comment: Additionally, the following is thrown when using View.of(context).display.size: _AssertionError ('dart:ui/window.dart': Failed assertion: line 106 pos 12: '<optimized out>': is not true.

Comment: could  it be device specific issue(linux) as you've included the tag 

Comment: I figured it could be something like that. After a bit more digging, it looks like displays is null, so anything after PlatformDispatcher.instance.displays returns null and doesn't work. That's the reason, I guess.

Comment: does it happen for all project & device, btw can you share the flutter version. My test device was chrome . creating a git issue will might be better ig

Comment: That's not relevant as the intended platform is Linux Desktop only. Flutter version is 3.13.4

Answer (score 0):

Try [desktop_window](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_window)! It should help you.

```
import 'package:desktop_window/desktop_window.dart';

Future testWindowFunctions() async {
    Size size = await DesktopWindow.getWindowSize();
    print(size);
    await DesktopWindow.setWindowSize(Size(500,500));

    await DesktopWindow.setMinWindowSize(Size(400,400));
    await DesktopWindow.setMaxWindowSize(Size(800,800));

    await DesktopWindow.resetMaxWindowSize();
    await DesktopWindow.toggleFullScreen();
    bool isFullScreen = await DesktopWindow.getFullScreen();
    await DesktopWindow.setFullScreen(true);
    await DesktopWindow.setFullScreen(false);
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! I already have a package that can manage the size and position of the window, I just need something to dynamically give me the correct value I should set the width to.